# Using Delphi FMX Effects on TMapView Objects

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

Is it possible to Use Delphi FMX effects like `TGlowEffect` on TMapview objects (`TMapCircle`).

FMX effects supposed to work with visible objects, if TMapView objects are derived from the Object Class, it should work I believe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you are out of luck on this.

First of all `TMapView` is a wrapper for Map API that is available on iOS and Android platforms. This means that the contents of `TMapView` isn't really rendered by FMX but instead underlying Map API.

I see you also assume that because `TMapView` objects are derived from `TObject` class that this should allow you to attack effects to them.

Well I'm afraid your assumption is wrong. `TObject` is pretty much a base class for all other classes whether they represent visual components or not. For instance [TFileStream](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TFileStream) is descendant from `TObject` and it has nothing to do with visual appearance of your application.

I'm guessing you might have confused `TObject` with `TFmxObject` class. But then again `TFmxObject` still does not support attaching effects to. Your object needs to be descendet from at least [TControl](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Controls.TControl) in order to provide functionality of using animations and effects.

The only other option would be if your class would also be inheriting (using multiple-inheritance) from `IEffectContainer` and `ITriggerEffect` interfaces which are actually providing functionality of working with Effects in the first palce.